# SQS/task-queue job retry count strategy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, distributed, task-queue, amazon-sqs

I'm implementing a task queue with Amazon SQS ( but i guess the question applies to any task-queue ) , where the workers are expected to take different action depending on how many times the job has been re-tried already ( move it to a different queue, increase visibility timeout, send an alert..etc )

What would be the best way to keep track of failed job count? I'd like to avoid having to keep a centralized db for job:retry-count records. Should i look at time spent in the queue instead in a monitoring process? IMO that would be ugly or un-clean at best, iterating over jobs until i find ancient ones..

thanks!
Andras

Comment: This question needs a modern answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933525/retrying-messages-where-my-code-fails-with-aws-sqs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142954/amazon-sqs-how-to-control-the-number-of-retries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon just released Simple workflow serice (swf) which you can think of as a more sophisticated/flexible version of GAE Task queues.

It will let you monitor your tasks (with hearbeats), configure retry strategies and create complicated workflows. It looks pretty promising abstracting out task dependencies, scheduling and fault tolerance for tasks (esp. asynchronous ones)

Checkout http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-intro-to-swf.html for overview.

Answer (score 10):

There is another simpler way. With your message you can request ApproximateReceiveCount information and base your retry logic on that. This way you won't have to keep it in the database and can calculate it from the message itself.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ReceiveMessage.html

Answer (score 6):

I've had good success combining SQS with SimpleDB.  It is "centralized", but only as much as SQS is.

Every job gets a record in simpleDB and a task in SQS.  You can put any information you like in SimpleDB like the job creation time.  When a worker pulls a job from the queue it can grab the corresponding record from simpleDB to determine it's history.  You can see how old the job is, and you can see how many times it has been attempted.  Once you're done, you can add worker data to the SimpleDB record (completion time, outcome, logs, errors, stack-trace, whatever) and acknowledge the message from SQS.

I prefer this method because it helps diagnose faults by providing lots of debug info for failed tasks.  It also allows workers to handle the job differently depending on how long the job has been queued, how many failures it's had, etc.

It also gives you the ability to query SimpleDB directly and calculate things like average time per task, percent failure rate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

SQS stands for "Simple Queue Service" which, in concept is the incorrect name for that service. The first and foremost feature of a "Queue" is FIFO (First in, First out), and SQS lacks that. Just wanting to clarify.

Also, Azure Queue Services lacks that as well. For the best cloud Queue service, use Azure's Service Bus since it's a TRUE Queue concept.

Comment: SQS now offers FIFO queues