# Amazon SQS how to control the number of retries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, worker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am configuring a [beanstalk worker environment to deal with periodic tasks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-tiers.html#worker-periodictasks)

When the requested URL is not responding with status `200` Elastic Beanstalk will put the task again in the queue.

How can I configure the number or retries?

I know the explanation is somewhere hidden behind `ErrorVisibilityTimeout`, `InactivityTimeout`, `Dead Letter Queues`... but these concepts are still not growing green in my inefficient mind.

For example I just want to configure *maximum number of retries 0* so there is try but not any retry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Enable Dead Letter Queues, and set the DLQ Maximum Receives value to 1. This means that a message can only be received (and not deleted) one time before it is sent to the Dead Letter Queue.

#### Update, adding screenshots

This field is found into the beanstalk environment admin into `Configuration > Worker Configuration > Advanced Options`:

[image]

Or into the the SQS Queue admin into `Queue Actions > Configure Queue`:

[image]

Changing the value in one place will propagate the change to the other place.

Comment: I have added some screenshots to the answer because I was having difficulties to find the proper place to make the proposed change.

Comment: nice answer, helped me to discover that there is a inactivity timeout preference that caused my tasks to end early!