# AWS Lambda retrying in case of timeouts, even though retry attempts is set to 0

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function which can time out sometimes depending on the payload. And in case of a timeout, I don't want my function to get retried. For that reason, I have set max retry attempts to 0. But somehow I can see timed-out functions getting retried.

Any idea how to stop the retrying?

The retries are happening every 30 minutes and the lambda costs have shot up because of this.

[image]

Comment: How is this function being invoked, are you invoking it in code or is it being done automatically from some service (e.g. SQS, API Gateway, etc)?

Comment: invocation is via SQS.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142954/amazon-sqs-how-to-control-the-number-of-retries. Basically you need to setup a DLQ, set max receive count to 1. That will prevent retries.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python SDK to trigger these lambdas then it might be the SDK that is performing the retry rather than AWS.

See this page https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-retry-timeout-sdk/

The SDK could be set to retry the function if it hasn't received as response due to a timeout

Comment: The trigger is by SQS, not any SDK.