# Amazon SQS sendMessageBatch() response and retries

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I wanted to clear something up. So this function returns a response for successful and failed batch entries. For failed batch entries if I set the maximum recieves for a message attribute for the dead letter queue to 3 found here [Amazon SQS how to control the number of retries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42142954/amazon-sqs-how-to-control-the-number-of-retries) are the batches retried immediately before the response or are they retried asynchronously.

```
public SendMessageBatchResponse sendBatch(List<SendMessageBatchRequestEntry> entryList){
       return this.sqsClient.sendMessageBatch(SendMessageBatchRequest.builder().queueUrl(this.queueUrl).entries(entryList).build());}
```

It's not clear from the aws docs what is the case.

Comment: What `maxRecieved` are you talking about? What is your code, what are you calling and how?

Comment: Added details on the post by maximum receives I meant the number of retries specificed for sqs before sending to the dead letter queue as for the code I added the code to the description

Comment: The maximum receives has NOTHING to do with sending messages / message batches, that is a configuration on the queue itself in terms of how many times a message can be received.

Comment: Ok so basically the response from this function has nothing to do with the aws lambda service called by sqs it just returns the messages status of reaching sqs am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.